# Unable to Set TimePicker in Blazorise Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, timepicker, blazorise

I need to bind time picker initial value from my model.

[time picker as addon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydn1P.png)

It is initialized  TimePicker? timePicker = new();

[full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9mVX.png)

I have tried both ways:
timePicker = new TimePicker() { Time = appSetting.CashOrderExecutionTime.TimeOfDay };
timePicker.Time = appSetting.CashOrderExecutionTime.TimeOfDay;

The currentValue, Time is changing that I can see in watch, but in front end it is showing 00:00
the default one.. or null if I make TimeSpan as nullable...

[front-end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Zsld.png)

Yes.. I am able to get the updated value from timePicker.Time after changing it.. but the issue is in set value. .. It is always picking the default

code mentioned above...

Comment: Can you add the code in text to the question? a link to undesirable.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your doing two-way binding properly. Either use the built in two-way binding or inhert from `InputBase`

I would make use of HTML5 input type `time` paired with two way binding. This will give you a native feel for every application.

```
<input type="time" @bind-value="StartDateTime">

@code
{
     public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to make a component out of this with two-way binding I would recommend to inherit `@inherits InputBase<DateTime>` and change the binding to `@bind="CurrentValue"` .

Answer (score 0):

You should never initialize Blazor components using `new`. This is wrong:

```cs
TimePicker? timePicker = new();
```

Instead add the component in your page like this:

```
<Addon AddonType="AddonType.Body">
    <TimePicker @ref="@timePicker" TValue="TimeSpan?" @bind-Time="@selectedTime" />
</Addon>

@code{
    TimePicker<TimeSpan?> timePicker;

    TimeSpan? selectedTime;
}
```

[Documentation](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/time-picker)